# How do I access script B,C,D singularly in script A?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've ran into a problem in my dialogue system.

I have a script "dialogue Manager", which takes in a "dialogue Holder" script for input/output with the user. Each npc will have its own dialogue holder to be passed to the dialogue manager when the player is close to the npc and presses spacebar.

In the dialogueManager I reference the dialogue holder script like this:

```
public dialogueHolder dh;
```

In the dialogueHolder script I have this code to initialize the dialogueHolder into the dialogueManager:

```
dManager.dialogueHolder = this;
```

This works fine when using the base dialogueHolder script, but its only a template for the individual npcs' dialogues. how could I make multiple dialogue holders that I can reference the same way in dialogueManager? For instance, I have a script dialogueHolder_yellowMage, which has certain dialogue pertaining to a mage npc, how can I reference this into the dh variable in DialogueManager? Because the dialogueHolder_yellowMage has a different title from dialogueHolder, I cannot reference it this way.

---

I've attempted to change

```
public dialogueHolder dh;
```

to

```
public Object dh;
```

but then I can't reference any of the variables in the dialogueHolder scripts.

Sorry for the wall of text, I'm new to stackOverflow and C#. Please help a newbie out!

Comment: read up about inheritance. if you derive dialogueHolder_yelllowMage from dialogueHolder it should "fit" into the variable (of type dialogueHolder). another option would be to use Interfaces. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx

Comment: I'm not quite understand your architecture, but anyway. If you make your dialogueHolder_yellowMage script inherit dialogueHolder then you will be able to reference it in the manager.

Comment: Awesome! I really appreciate the quick responses. Thank you!!!!!

Comment: @GPlourde It seems like you're not using C# objects correctly - it sounds like you're defining a unique script for each npc? I've worked on a few Unity dialogue systems so I know for sure that's not necessary.

Comment: @Luke how would I have individual dialogues for each npc on a single script? It seems i have to give each npc a seperate instance of the dialogue holder, since they will all have different strings from one another. Is there a better way? Id like to improve my bad coding practices haha.

Comment: @GPlourde Yep instancing is the way to go (but instancing and creating a new class are two very different things :) ). I.e. Attach a 'DialogueHolder' component to each of your NPCs. DialogueHolder itself then has e.g. `public string DialogueToSay;` which you'll see in the inspector on each of those NPCs (and set it differently for each one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Classes vs Instances

It seems like you're doing this kind of thing:

```
public class dialogueHolder_yellowMage {

    public string MessageToSay;

}

public class dialogueHolder_redMage {

    public string MessageToSay;

}

public class dialogueHolder_blueMan {

    public string MessageToSay;

}

..

// public dialogueHolder_? dh;
public object dh; // Only this would work, but it's not what you want!
```

The first thing to note is they're all repeating the same thing (or at the very least, repeating the same *concept*). Rather than having a unique class per NPC, instead, have a class that represents dialogue:

```
public class DialogueHolder {

    // The message they'll say
    public string MessageToSay;

}

...

// Then we *instance* one for each of our NPCs:
DialogueHolder yellowMage = new DialogueHolder();
yellowMage.MessageToSay = "I'm feeling great!";

DialogueHolder redMage = new DialogueHolder();
redMage.MessageToSay = "I'm so angry!";
..
```

In this case, they're all using *instances* of the same *class*. That means you can now do `public DialogueHolder dh;` and that'll work fine.

## Inheritance

If a class describes a concept then inheritance is describes *related concepts*. For example, a Dog is a type of Animal. A Mage is a type of NPC. But dialogue doesn't often have these distinctive categories, so inheritance probably isn't what you'll want to be using.

## Unity Components

As you're using Unity, we can turn those instances into something nice and visual - make use of *components* in the inspector. A component script looks like this:

```
// DialogueHolder.cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;    

public class DialogueHolder : MonoBehaviour { // (This is also inheritance)

    // The message they'll say
    public string MessageToSay;

}
```

**Time for a common misconception:** Unity defaults to creating component scripts. That often makes people think *all* classes must inherit MonoBehaviour, which isn't how Unity works. Only inherit MonoBehaviour when something is actually useful as a component.

Click on one of your NPC's in the Editor and then the take a look at the inspector; you'll see an "Add Component" button. Click on that and you'll then get an option for Scripts:

[image: Adding a script in Unity Indie]

In there, you'll then be able to select your `DialogueHolder` class. Once you've added it, you'll see this kind of thing in the inspector:

[image: Instance of a script]

*Unity has instanced the class for you as a component of the NPC's gameobject*

This is wonderfully useful; you can then edit the `Message To Say` individually. Most `public` fields in your class will be visible (and editable) within the inspector, so you can add a bunch of other dialogue relevant fields:

```
// DialogueHolder.cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;    

public class DialogueHolder : MonoBehaviour {

    // The message they'll say
    public string MessageToSay;

    // Some kind of 2D chat head image
    public Texture2D ChatHead;

    // etc!

}
```

## Getting that DialogueHolder from a GameObject

So let's say your player is walking around the scene and is within chat range of some gameObject. You could use [tagging](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tags.html) to quickly check if gameObject `x` is an NPC or not. Store a list of all available NPCs by [finding all GameObjects that are tagged as an NPC](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html) as your scene starts up, then loop through checking how far away the player is from each of them. When the player is in range of one of them, you can then get hold of the DialogueHolder like this:

```
// Try getting the dialogue holder:
DialogueHolder dh = aGameObject.GetComponent<DialogueHolder>();

if (dh == null) {

    // This NPC doesn't feel like talking (you didn't give it a DialogueHolder)

} else {

    // Do something with dh

}
```

A fully functional dialogue system is beyond the scope here of course, but that's the basics anyway!

Comment: @abatishchev The code didn't need reformatting - The style it was in is the common one for Unity3D.

Comment: @abatishchev i.e. take a look at some of the [Unity API examples](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html) that were [linked in this answer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tags.html). Probably best to avoid enforcing *your* preferred style onto other users.

Comment: I just made it in the _common_ one for C# (see [MSDN guidance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx)). It's always up to you. P.S. That style sucks. My humble opinion.

Comment: @abatishchev This is a Unity question and Unity has its own convention; FWIW I like both styles (out of necessity) but just because *you* don't like the Unity convention doesn't mean you should change answers to something else :)

Comment: I didn't know that is Unity style. So just formatted to follow the common C# style. Didn't mean to enforce anything, really.

Comment: @abatishchev All the more reason to never *change* the style of code, because it's either like that for a reason or it's somewhat personal (it's also kind of interesting that it felt insulting). If it had no formatting then sure, by all means add it of course.

Comment: I didn't have any intent to insult, not at all. I'm sorry if it seemed this way.

Comment: This is great!! I really appreciate all the help from everyone. I read up on abstract classes & interfaces, but realized instantiating the same script for each npc would be much more efficient. Thanks for everything!